# Error Message is not printing 2nd time without page refresh while checking validation using Ajax submition

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

"(#errmsg)" not printing 2nd time without page refresh while checking validation using Ajax submition

```
<div class="col-md-2">  
      <input type="text" id="pay_containt" maxlength='51' class="form-control"    name="pay_containt"  required>
      <span id="errmsg" class="emsg-fontsize"></span>  
    </div>
    <script>
  var pay_containt = $('#pay_containt').val()
    if(pay_containt == ""){
       $("#errmsg").html("Enter Contents.").fadeOut(18000);
        return false;
     }

 </script>
```

Comment: You need to validate on some event. In you example the validation code will run just once and then only on page refresh

Answer (score 0):

You should attach an event listener to your `#pay_containt` element which responds to changes in the input text.

```js
var errorMessage = $('#errmsg')
$('#pay_containt').on('change', function (event) {
  if (!this.value) {
    errorMessage.text("Enter Contents.").fadeOut(18000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2">  
      <input type="text" id="pay_containt" maxlength='51' class="form-control"    name="pay_containt"  required>
      <span id="errmsg" class="emsg-fontsize"></span>  
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Need to attach some kind of event to the textbox and trigger validation each time event is fired.
2. You need to show the element and then fadeout.

Example Snippet with `keyup` event:

```js
var errorMessage = $('#errmsg')
$('#pay_containt').on('keyup', function (event) {
  if (!$(this).val().trim()) {
    errorMessage.text("Enter Contents.").show().fadeOut(1000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2">  
      <input type="text" id="pay_containt" maxlength='51' class="form-control"    name="pay_containt"  required>
      <span id="errmsg" class="emsg-fontsize"></span>  
    </div>
```